# c# call jar file with windows form

Tags: java, c#, forms

I'm working with apktool GUI but i don't know how to call jar file with a windows form. I just want to make the apktool GUI program so i don't have to run cmd and type the command and file path.

Here is the code i want to make.

call apktool

```
Process.Start(java, String.Join(" ", args));
```

Prepare the arguments

```
string[] args = { "-jar",
apktool, "d",
"-f ",
filename,
decompiled };
```

apktool = The path to apktool

filename = the APK file name

decompiled = The Apktool create a Decompiled folder. Decompiled is a folder name.

"d" = decompile mode

"-f" = overwrites file if it exist (force)

The final command should look like

```
-jar c:\apktool.exe d -f c:\bf.apk c:\decompiled
```

but i want the program to call the jar file on any location and not just in C:/

Comment: if some of your filePaths contains spaces, it won't work. you should terminate such strings with double quotes like this: "\"" + filename + "\""

Comment: Are you sure? in cmd i always write this command "-jar c:\apktool.exe d -f c:\bf.apk c:\decompiled"

Comment: yes. I am sure) there are no spaces in your sample paths. if they existed (like in c:\program files\microsoft) the problem would appear

Comment: ok. is it possible to use Open File Dialog and |DataDirectory| with this? i want is users can open file dialog and select the .APK file to decompile and the Decompiled folder will be created where the program located instead only in C:/, only in D:/test/ or whatever. it would be bad if the program only works in C:/ and not anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ProcessStartInfo to add arguments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx